# HATEOAS POST link in HAL

Tags: java, spring-boot, hateoas, spring-hateoas

How do I describe POST links in HAL?

I'm designing a RESTful API with HATEOAS constraints, similar to [Wikipedia's HATEOAS example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) but expressed in HAL JSON (dropping the scheme, host, etc. for clarity):

```
GET /accounts/12345

{
  "id" : 12345,
  "balance" : 100.00
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "/accounts/12345"
    },
    "transfer" : {
      "href" : "/accounts/12345/transfer{?amount,target}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}
```

To perform the "transfer" action, the client would presumably do:

```
GET /accounts/12345/transfer?amount=100.00,target=54321

{
  "id" : 34567,
  "amount" : 100.00
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "/transfers/34567"
    },
    "source" : {
      "href" : "/account/12345"
    },
    "target" : {
      "href" : "/account/54321"
    }
  }
}
```

Invoking the "transfer" link via GET creates a new ressource in "transfers". But doing a GET to create a new resource is not idempotent and it "feels" wrong; a RESTful resource centric API would POST:

```
POST {amount: 10.00, source: 12345, target: 54321}  /transfers/

{
  "id" : 34567,
  "amount" : 100.00
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "/transfers/34567"
    },
    "source" : {
      "href" : "/account/12345"
    },
    "target" : {
      "href" : "/account/54321"
    }
  }
}
```

But how do I describe this POST and the required form elements in HAL so the client can just do the "Right Thing" without being hard-coded? Perhaps something like:

```
{
  "id" : 12345,
  "balance" : 100.00
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "/accounts/12345"
    },
    "transfer" : {
      "href" : "/transfers{?amount,source,target}",
      "templated" : true,
      "method" : "POST"
    }
  }
}
```

But `method` not part of the [HAL specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08) and there's no analogous identifier -- so it feels like I'm on the wrong track...

Perhaps my client should just "know" that a GET of `transfer` returns matching transfer resources, and a POST to `transfer` creates a new transfer resource.

FWIW, my implementation uses Spring Boot 2 with Spring HATEOAS so the follow-up question is how to express this with Spring HATEOAS...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that with HAL. Mike Kelly, the creator of HAL, [states on GitHub](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal_specification/issues/24#issuecomment-71314321)

> The "HAL way" of doing this is to use the link rel documentation to convey the available methods in a human readable form. ie. your barks example would look like this (notice the "barks" link rel is now a URL)
>
> ```
> {
>    "_links": {
>         "http://docs.example.com/barks": { "href": "/v1/dogs/1/barks" }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> and if a developer fetches the URL http://docs.example.com/barks in a browser, the documentation can specify the available methods, valid request bodies, potential response codes, response bodies, etc. The developer will then codify this into the client she is building.

This is a major flaw of the HAL spec imho, but there are other mediatypes that tackle this issue, like [Mason](https://github.com/JornWildt/Mason/wiki/Mason-features#other-hypermedia-elements) or the HAL extension [HAL-FORMS](http://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/). It might be worth checking these out, though I'm not sure how they integrate with Spring.